# Make 1 associative array out of 2 arrays in Actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

How do i make 1 array that has the keys of 1st array & its values are the values of the 2nd array in Actionscript 3.0?

Below is my [WRONG] code. Package import left out.

```
public class myPages extends Sprite {
    protected var pageNames:Array = [];
    protected var pageLayoutNo:Array = [];
    private var pageLayoutNames:Object = new Object();


    public function assignNamesLayouts {

        //all the names of the pages
        for(i=0; i<totalPages; i++) {
            var pageMc:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
            pageMc.name = menu.config.pages.page[i].@name;
            pageNames[i]= pageMc.name;
        }

        //all layout numbers
        for(i=0; i<totalPages; i++) {
            pageLayoutNo[i] = menu.config.layoutNum.layNum[i];
        }

    setNames(pageNames);
    setPLNo(pageLayoutNo);
    setLayoutNames(pageLayoutNo,pageNames);

    }

    protected function setNames(a:Array) {
        pageNames = a;
    }

    protected function setPLNo(a:Array) {
        pageLayoutNo = a;

    }

    protected function setLayoutNames(a:Array, b:Array) {
        var maps:Object = new Object();
        maps.no = a;
        maps.nm = b;
        for each(var k:int in a) {
           maps[k] = b;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should try employing `Dictionary` instead of your two arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will agree with @Vesper. Closest solution to the `associative array` will be [Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html). I also will add, some ideas for you. If your collection will have keys as Strings, you could use simple Object:

```
var keyName: String = "key1";
var anotherKey: String = "key2";
var collection: Object = {};
collection[keyName] = new MovieClip();
collection[anotherKey] = new Sprite();

trace(collection[keyName]);
```

If you want to use 2 arrays: one for keys, another one for values, you will need several functions(place object with key, get object by key, get object by value, remove object by key, etc.) to manage them, because indexes in arrays must be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is really what you want, but you could do it by creating an array of objects like this:

```
var newArray=combineArrays("name", arr1,"number",arr2);
function combineArrays(name1, arr1,name2, arr2){
 var newArr=new Array();
 for(var i<arr1){
  var obj=new Object();
  obj[name1]=arr1[i];
  obj[name2]=arr2[i];
  newArr.push(obj);
 }
}
```

Then you can search on the object names or values for either object.